# Java Converted List of Tuple4s to a Nested Map

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a list of tuple4 with 4 different data types inside it. `List<Tuple4<String, Boolean, String, Integer>`

I'm trying to group this into a map of the following type: `Map<String, Map<Boolean, Map<String, List<Integer>>>`.

How would I go about this in Java 11?

For context, I'm trying to save this map to Elastic Search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the easiest thing is a straightforward loop, with

```
for (Tuple4<...> tuple : list) {
  map.computeIfAbsent(tuple.first, k -> new HashMap<>()).computeIfAbsent(tuple.second, k -> new HashMap<>()).computeIfAbsent(tuple.third, k -> new ArrayList<>()).add(tuple.fourth);
}
```

Comment: `HashMap::new` -> `k -> new HashMap<>()`  and `ArrayList::new` -> `k -> new ArrayList<>()`